# $\mathbb{Q}$ is in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, statistics

> Prove that the set of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ belongs to the Borel σ-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$

I was just thinking about the method I would go about proving this

I was thinking if we can write

$$\mathbb{Q} = \bigcup_{x \in \mathbb{Q}} \left \{ x \right \}$$

And then if we prove the {x} is in the Borel σ-algebra then the union is too?

If there's a method to prove this, It would really help thank you

Comment: what you did is perfect.

Comment: I believe you want to prove that "$\mathbb{Q}$ belongs to the Borel sigma algebra", not that it is a sigma algebra itself. Same thing about $\{x\}$.

Comment: Sorry yes I forgot to add that in

Comment: Also, your question is about the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, not an arbitrary $\sigma$-algebra. So, I believe the  intented title is "$\mathbb{Q}$ is in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra"   and where you wrote "... prove the $\{x\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra then...", you meant "... prove the $\{x\}$ is in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra then...".

Comment: I have posted an answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your argument is right. Here are the details.

It is enough to prove that for all $x\in \Bbb Q$ (in fact, for all $x\in \Bbb R$), $\{x\}$ is **in** the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.  Then, since
$$\mathbb{Q} = \bigcup_{x \in \mathbb{Q}} \left \{ x \right \}$$
and since such union is countable (because $\Bbb Q$ is countable), we have that $\Bbb Q$ is **in** the  the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.